# Issue regarding completion suggester?

Tags: elasticsearch

have used completion suggester for suggestions.So my question is I have created a type called "states" in one of indices and I have indexed around 10k documents to that type.

For some reason I have dropped that type and re-indexed the documents.

Here is the mystery while I'm querying for that type it is showing me the old suggestions.

We are using elasticsearch2.2.0

Please let me know if there are options to get the results based on the current type documents.

Thanks in advance,

Kartheek Gummaluri

Comment: What does "dropped that type" mean? Did you delete the index or simply delete-by-query all documents? (since it's not possible to delete a mapping type in ES 2.x)

Comment: I have deleted the type

Comment: How did you do that? Can you show the command you used?

Comment: GET test/code/_delete

Comment: Are you using a plugin or something because the `_delete` endpoint doesn't exist in ES? It's very unlikely that hitting that URL with GET yields anything (should get an error), and certainly not delete anything.

Comment: Actually I'm using this command to delete the type

curl -XDELETE "http://localhost:9200/testindex/pincodes"

Comment: Well, deleting a mapping type is [not supported anymore](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking_20_mapping_changes.html#_types_may_no_longer_be_deleted) since 2.0, so I'm wondering what output your getting with ES 2.2. Can you share it? You should get `No handler found for uri [/testindex/pincodes] and method [DELETE]`

Comment: Did you see my last comment above? Any chance to get this solved?